# how does gmail capture mouse events without listeners?

Tags: javascript, events, gmail, event-listener

I am trying to simulate a mouseover on the email address in my gmail inbox:

[image]

Gmail opens a popup with more info about the person when I hover oder the sender name.

However the popup does not open when I trigger a mouseover, mouseenter, mouseleaver, hover, etc. programatically.

I also don't see any event listeners attached to the element when I query for them in the console:

```
getEventListeners(document.getElementById(...))
```

How does google know that the mouse is on the element without using events?